# sync remote repository with remote website

Tags: git, github, repository

I've created a local development site and a remote live site.  I created a remote repository and pushed my local changes to it.  I now want to sync my remote website with the remote repository.  How do I do this

Answer (score 0):

Do I suppose correctly that you are on github (given the tags used for your request) ?

On a 'regular' git repo, I would use post-receive hooks, so on github I would investigate [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) on push if I were you.  When pushing to remote repo, push to the website or something like that.  They also have [deployment](https://developer.github.com/guides/delivering-deployments/) [specific](https://developer.github.com/guides/automating-deployments-to-integrators/) stuff but I have never used them.